# zip command is not ignoring items marked by -x flag

Tags: shell-script, zip

I have the following zip command:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

zip -r dist/output.zip . \
-x dist \
-x .idea \
-x node_modules \
-x scripts \
-x *.zip \
-x .git \
-x .gitignore \
-x .npmignore
```

I am simply trying to zip everything in the current directory, but ignore everything marked by -x.

Looks like the command is working, except it's not ignoring anything, it's zipping everything.

Comment: I also tried `zip dist/output.zip -r .` instead of `zip -r dist/output.zip .` and that didn't seem to make a difference, which is weird

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, it doesn't seem to be very intuitive.

The [manual says](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip), under the `--include` option

> So to include dir, a directory directly under the current directory, use
>   `zip -r foo . -i "dir/*"`

and that

> Note that currently the trailing / is needed for directories

The include option is referred to under `-x`, so it's safe to assume to same rules work there.

Judging from the examples, you need to add the `/*` to all excluded directories to have them actually excluded. Just listing `-x dir/` will not work, it will still save the files in the directory, just not the directory itself. So:

```
$ mkdir foo bar
$ touch foo/a bar/a
$ zip -r test.zip . -x "foo/*"
updating: bar/ (stored 0%)
updating: bar/a (stored 0%)
$
```

Comment: it's so strange that the -r flag can come before the include option. it's beyond me why the -r flag comes before the output argument.

Comment: probably won't try this out until tomorrow, but if it works, will give you the green cuisine

Comment: @AlexanderMills, what does the location of the `-r` flag matter? The usual idiom would be that flags come first, then files/targets/whatever, though GNU tools (and anything that uses the GNU version of `getopt`) accept them anywhere on the command line.

Comment: in this case, doesn't matter, but in general when you have a modifier, usually it's proximate to the thing being modified, otherwise the modifier could be modifying something else. Also semantics, the user doesn't know for sure that -r means recursive (without looking at the docs), so when you are trying to interpret the meaning, it's more difficult when -r can appear anywhere.

Comment: I am not a big fan of shorthand in general. hate it. absolutely hate it. CLIs should require users to specify input and output with flags. The following `zip file files` should be required to be `zip --out file --include files`

Comment: @AlexanderMills, it modifies the behaviour of the whole program, so it makes sense to put the closer to the program name, and not later, yes? If the brevity bothers you, I think you could write `--recurse-paths`, which is quite a lot simpler to interpret.

Comment: yeah, another nice thing with requiring flags, is that order of arguments no longer matters